# embedded tomcat error in maven project

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

i am trying to run my project using 'tomcat:run' command in my maven project build using eclipse. here i am experiencing some issues:

this is my pom.xml plugin code:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                 <port>9999</port>
                  <path>/webapp</path>
                  <warFile>${project.basedir}/target/${project.build.finalName}.war</warFile>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

here is the complete error stack trace

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving interface method "javax.servlet.jsp.JspApplicationContext.getExpressionFactory()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;" the class loader (instance of org/apache/jasper/servlet/JasperLoader) of the current class, org/apache/jsp/index_jsp, and the class loader (instance of org/codehaus/plexus/classworlds/realm/ClassRealm) for the method's defining class, javax/servlet/jsp/JspApplicationContext, have different Class objects for the type javax/el/ExpressionFactory used in the signature
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspInit(index_jsp.java:22)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.init(HttpJspBase.java:52)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:159)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

how can i solve this issue?

any suggestion will be appreciated

thank you

Comment: You have two options for adding to your projects libraries, such as jsp-api.jar, el-api.jar, servlet-api.jar, etc:

Add these libraries as external jars in your Java Build Path;
Add them as maven dependencies, setting the provided scope for each of them, for example:
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

You need to include servlet dependencies as @Ashwin said.

like this:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I took this example config from this [blog post](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/embed-tomcat-maven-project-run-tomcat-maven/). The version of servlet api and jstl may change depending on tomcat version.